# Can't load Chrome profile with Selenium on Debian

Tags: python, debian, selenium-chromedriver

I've successfully managed to load a Chrome Profile on MAC and I was trying to replicate the same on Linux but without success (Debian). I'm using Python, and the following works just fine on a MAC

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

The same code on Debian, just doesn't work...

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/username/.config/google-chrome")
# I've tried also without the `--` but same outcome
# chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/username/.config/google-chrome")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver_linux', options=chrome_options)
```

I honestly now idea what's wrong. I'm using chromedriver 2.45 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/ and the issue is related to "Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" ...

In terms of launching Chrome, they both works. The difference is that on MAC it loads the profile, on Debian it doesn't.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is this the same version you used on mac??

Comment: yep, is a different binary of course.

Comment: Is it named as `chromedriver_linux` and located in the same directory as this script

Comment: And is there any error/warning ??

Comment: yes, that's the name - no errors what so ever, just empty profile on debian...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so after many headaches, apparently this is something to do with the fact than I'm using **CRD** (Chrome Remote Desktop) to connect to the Linux instances!

In fact, you can check the profile location loading *chrome://version*. When connecting with CRD, this changes from the usual `/home/user/.config/google-chrome` to `/home/user/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-profile/`

All I needed to do is basically replace with the CRD directory to get all the profile information I wanted!

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome")
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-profile/")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver_linux', options=chrome_options)
```

Hopefully this will be helpful for others! :)